# Set formula for each new tab/sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to assign a formula to each new tab. I am getting an error code (Missing ] after element list. (line 10, file "Code")

```
function makeTabs() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var last = sheet.getLastRow();//identifies the last active row on the sheet

//loop through the code until each row creates a tab.

for(var i=1; i<last; i++){

var tabName = sheet.getRange(i+1,9).getValue();//get the range in column I and get the value.

var create = ss.insertSheet(tabName);//create a new sheet with the value

var formulas = [

  ['=transpose('Form Responses 1'!J2:O2)'],

  ['=Arrayformula(IF(A2:A="",,VLookup(A2:A,ImportedData!A1:S,{2,11,15,18,17,19},0)))']] ;


var cell = sheet.getRange("A2:B2");

cell.setFormulas(formulas);
}
}
```

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try Escaping inner single quotes like this:

```
['=transpose(\'Form Responses 1\'!J2:O2)']
```

Comment: Thanks! transposing J2:O2 works...How would I transpose J(i+1):O(i+1)? Is that possible to do ?  I am new at coding scripts... can't seem to find an answer in my searches.